# How do I improve the PowerShell script to retrieve data from azure storage with conditions which taking longer to retrieve

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get help with a PowerShell code that retrieves Azure Storage blobs that match a specific name pattern and were last modified within a specific date range. And get a list of Log backup blobs for selected database. Logs which less than differential backup and greater than point intime. In general I'm working script that helps me to do point Intime recovery.

`$logBlobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $containerName -Prefix $prefix -Context $context |  Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*$db1*" } -and ($_.LastModified -lt $pointInTimeRestore1 -and $_.LastModified -gt $diffBackupDate)} | #Sort-Object -Property $_.LastModified | Select-Object -First 100`

Comment: Please detail what the issue is? You have posted a script snippet, with no details about what's not working with it.